# Combining / Sorting two datetime tables/arrays/lists

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

I have two MySQL tables, both with Timestamp (DATE/TIME)... I need a query to combine them and sort them together, by timestamp (2013-08-21 13:13:47).

```
Table 1
---------------------------------------
Timestamp |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  


Table 2
---------------------------------------
Timestamp |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  | Col 4
```

I want to print out

```
PRINT OUT (in order by timestamp)
----------------
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  | Col 4
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  | Col 4
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  | Col 4
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3 
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  | Col 4
Timestamp  |  Col 1  |  Col 2  | Col 3  | Col 4
```

What is the simplest way to do this? Should I put the two tables into an array and then sort? or should I do this with a sql query?

I'm using PHP & MySQL...

Comment: How do you intend to put a timestamp value in column 4?  Are the types compatible?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's just the way formatting looks on here, my intent is to have timestamp in the same col... sorry about that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff also, that is what the print out looks like... I only need to print it out... not store it, so type doesn't matter anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Table1.Col1 has the same kind of data as Table2.Col1, Table1.Col2 has the same kind of data as Table2.Col2, etc, then this is probably the easiest way. Tables in a union have to have the same number of columns. I use NULL to take the place of Col4.  You might want additional columns in the ORDER BY clause.

```
select T1.Timestamp, T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3, NULL as Col4
from Table1
union all
select T2.Timestamp, T2.Col1, T2.Col2, T2.Col3, T2.Col4
from Table2
order by Timestamp
```

It makes sense to do this only if the similarly named columns have the same kind of data. If Table1.Col1 contains names, and Table2.Col1 contains phone numbers, it doesn't make much sense to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a MySQL union to do this. A query like this will do it:

```
(
  SELECT
    id,
    NULL AS col,
    time
  FROM
    table1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT
    id,
    col,
    time
  FROM
    table2
)
ORDER BY time
```

That way your result set will contain all the same columns, where as if you did it in two queries with PHP you might end up with nonexistant indexes, plus its slower.

Here's a SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7416/10

Answer (score 0):

> What is the simplest way to do this? Should I put the two tables into an array and then sort? or should I do this with a sql query?

Your database is optimized for querying data, that includes to aggregate and collect data together as well as to sort and order it.

So you don't do that your own but let your database do that work.

So you do that with an SQL query. Most likely [`UNION` and `ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html), both explained in the manual of your database.